# Parse HTML meta tags in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

I'm trying to parse meta tags with Scala. I've tried just doing this with XML matching, like

```
`html // meta ...` etc,
```

but I'm getting a malformed-XML error because these meta tags on this particular page have no ending tag or `... />` enclosure.

So for the following HTML,

```
val html = """<meta name="description" content="This is some meta description">"""
```

I'm using the following regex matcher:

```
val metaDescription = """.*meta name="Description" content="([^"]+)"""".r
```

- When I try to match with `val metaDescription(desc) = html` I get a scala.MatchError.
- When I try with `metaDescription.findAllIn(html)` and iterate, I get the whole string--not just the description.

How can I just get the value inside `content` and nothing else?

**EDIT**

I got the result I wanted with:

```
metaDescription.findAllIn(html).matchData foreach {
  desc => println(desc.group(1))
}
```

but that seems like a long way around. Is there a better solution?

Comment: You should use an html parsing library

Comment: To repeat the above sentiment, you should use an html parsing library. Html is notoriously hard to parse when creating your own regexes, let someone else do the work for you. This is also the canonical answer on SO, look at just about any answer about parsing html with a regex and you'll find you're better off just using a parsing library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Scala XML and TagSoup](http://blog.dub.podval.org/2010/08/scala-and-tag-soup.html%20%22Scala%20and%20TagSoup%2a) provides one way to use tag soup directly with Scala XML.

If you are open to alternatives then [Scales Xml](https://github.com/chris-twiner/scalesXml) provides a similar useful approach to [parse html via alternative SAX parsers](http://scala-scales.googlecode.com/svn/sites/scales/scales-xml_2.9.2/0.4.4/FullParsing.html#Direct_SAX_XMLReader_Usage):

```
val html = loadXmlReader(htmlStream, parsers = AlternateSAXFactoryPool)
```

example factories for Tagsoup and Nu.Validator are provided on that link.

Comment: Ok, I agree with not reinventing the wheel--these are great, thank you